# Why are Angular Material fonts measured in pixels?

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

We are building an Angular Material app and our designer wants us to change all the css styles to use units measured in `em` because he's worried that anything measured in `px` will need multiple styles for different media query breakpoints. Currently, it appears that [Angular Material uses pixels](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/typography) for their typography. I am reluctant to override their styles considering that they've probably put a lot more time and effort into making it look right on as many platforms and devices as possible.

I also [read this](https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html) which talks about "scaleable pixels" in Material Design, but I don't understand how you would define a scaleable pixel in CSS since `sp` doesn't seem to be a valid unit of measure. Plus, I opened the `angular-material.css` file and indeed the fonts have `px` next to them. Hopefully someone can help me understand why this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

em is not a responsive format it is also pixel related it just orientates itself on the font size that the user can edit in their browser settings.

The only method right now with css is to use vw and vh to make text responsive to the screensize.
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you, but are my designer's fears warranted? Will the Angular Material Team's choice to use `px` cause us problems?

Comment: no you just have to include this meta tag (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and px values will be scaled to device resolution multiplicator (this calculation is processed automatically you dont have to do anything)